# Add a toolbar to a CDialog Window

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I created a SDI application and I created a Dialog Window. I want to add a toolbar to that dialog, so I coded like this :

```
int CAddNewEmployee::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CDialog::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
      return -1;

   CToolBar cToolBar;
   cToolBar.Create(this);
   cToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_MAINFRAME1);
   cToolBar.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
   cToolBar.SetBarStyle(CBRS_ALIGN_TOP | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY);
   RepositionBars(AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, 0);

   return 0;
```

}

but when I run the application nothing happen, there is no toolbar shown. I don't know if the code is right and how to make it shown.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your toolbar is destroyed at the end of the function as you made it a local variable. Make it a member variable instead.

Reference:
[How to add control bars to dialog boxes in MFC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141751)

Comment: Thank You, I did not thought about such Trace.

Comment: Is there a new link? This one 404s now.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, it's been a while and did forgot what really was on that tutorial, but based on my example in the question I had to add my Control declared in the class to not be destroyed at the end of the function.

You may check this link https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/141/Q141751/ (Adding Control Bars to Dialog Boxes in MFC)